# Android application closed unexpectedly

Tags: android, webview

I used the following code to download a file. It runs fine, but when I click the download button, the following error  comes: "Application mibooks has stopped unexpectedly."

How can I solve this problem in my code?

```
package mds.mibooks;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;


public class mibooks extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 setContentView(R.layout.webview);

                 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                 WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
                 WebView myWebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                 myWebView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


                /* WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                 webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
                */

            //   String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
                // myWebView1.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
                 myWebView1.loadUrl("http://www.mibooks.com/beta/");


                 myWebView1.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                long contentLength) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                             intent.setData(Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
                   intent.setType("*zip*"); 
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });

            }    
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace.

Comment: I hope, you are using Eclipse. Switch to DDMS perspective, then click on Logcat here you will see all the debug, warning and error logs. Whenever Android throws any exception, it generates its error log in the DDMS which tells us about the problem.

Comment: yeah you are right.. it showing many line i couldn't figure out. last line was:[ 02-24 10:21:54.381: DEBUG/SntpClient(67): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol] Note: one thing , "Application mibooks has stopped unexpectedly" error comes only when i give this statement "intent.setType("*zip*"); " if i comment that one works fine, but file will not be downloaded .

Comment: Try intent.setType("application/zip"); instead of intent.setType("zip"); Only zip doesn't seems an appropriate MIME type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android application stopped unexpectedly** it is normal scenario in android programming when any runtime error is occurred. i was not aware of this when i was throwing this question. I got solution for this problem that is..
 1. setContentView(R.layout.webview); and setContentView(R.layout.main); one layout is point to null.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps install the ADT plugin? See here:- [Cannot Make Andoid Apps Work](http://www.appdevroom.com/showthread.php?4-Cannot-make-my-Android-App-Work)